# Amazon login and acess to orders

Tags: python, cookies, beautifulsoup, request, amazon-product-api

**Problem:**
I've read myself trough articles for days and try to login into my amazon account with python. But I'm failing each time. Since every article has a different approach is very hard to find the potential error source. Especially as a lot of articles are older than 2-3 years.
I think from my current point of view the most straight forward way is to use `BeautifulSoup` `bs4`and `requests`. Which parser is the best is another discussion but I've seen `html.parser`, `html5lib` and `lxml` as most amazon login related articles are working with `html.parser` this is the one currently in my code even if I would love to use `lxml` or `html5lib` later on.
All kinds of input and feedback helps to summaries all important points and turnarounds.
I'm currently trying to get to the login page via `'https://www.amazon.de/gp/css/order-history?ref_=nav_orders_first'` as the `'https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin'` gives me an error, at least in my browser. So I'm going to a page where a user needs to login (my orders) to be forwarded to the login page and try to log in there. Is there a possibility to be logged out again when making a new `requests` to another subsite like switching pages? Also, I found an article using `with requests.Session() as s:`is this a better way to `request` a site compared to not doing with an intend and `Session()`.  I'm by the way using "de" in the URL but you can exchange that with "com" I guess.

**Current code:**

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

amazon_orders_url = r'https://www.amazon.de/gp/css/order-history?ref_=nav_orders_first'  # First time visit login
amazon_login_url = r'https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin'  # Not working by browser access

credentials = {'email': "EMAILADRESS", "password": "PASSWORD"}

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.129 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'en,de-DE;q=0.9,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7',
    'referer': 'https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin'}

# print(credentials['email'])  # print Email address

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    site = s.get(amazon_orders_url)  # , headers=headers

    # HTML parsing
    soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, "html.parser")  # Alternative "html5lib" / , "html.parser" / , "lxml"

    # Print whole page
    # print(soup)

    # Check if Anmelden/Login exists
    for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='a-box'):
        headline = div.h1
        print(headline)

    signin_data = {s["name"]: s["value"]
                   for s in soup.select("form[name=signIn]")[0].select("input[name]")
                   if s.has_attr("value")}

    # signin_data = {}
    # signin_form = soup.find('form', {'name': 'signIn'})
    # for field in signin_form.find_all('input'):
    #     try:
    #         signin_data[field['name']] = field['value']
    #     except:
    #         pass

    signin_data[u'email'] = credentials['email']
    signin_data[u'password'] = credentials['password']

    post_response = s.post('https://www.amazon.de/ap/signin', data=signin_data)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(post_response.text, "html.parser")

    warning = soup.find('div', {'id': 'message_warning'})
    # if warning:
        # print('Failed to login: {0}'.format(warning.text))

    print(soup)
    # print(post_response.content)
```

Comment: you're not posting with any headers, there are almost certainly some authentication type headers on amazon

Comment: @SuperStew I'm using `s.headers = headers`

Comment: well you're probably missing the auth ones that the server is going to look for.

Comment: @SuperStew How would that look like? As I haven't seen anybody using other headers other than default language?

Comment: login using your browser and inspect the requests. i'd be surprised if amazon didn't have some

Comment: I've done that and have all in front of me whats the name I should look for?

Comment: when i sign on to amazon in browser, there are two posts that happen. the first is for the email, then for the password. in the email post alone there are headers like `rtt`, `ect`, `content length`, and there are form data fields like `appActionToken`, `appAction`, `openid.return_to`, `workflowState`. You're probably going to need to get all these right to get it to work. Signing into a site like amazon is likely to be complicated. I would probably use selenium if i were you.

Comment: @SuperStew What's the advantage to use selenium?

Comment: Selenium controls the browser, so all the complicated javascript things and redirects etc are handled automatically. In selenium, you can essentially say "click login button", "type email", "type password", "click signin button", and so on

Comment: You should try Selenium. You can even use an exsiting profile of Chrome / Firefox in oder to log in. Few years back you could use mechanize, but it seesm that this is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Also I have a similar problem in my project so far I can obtain some of the parameters of the header to enter into the logging process.

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import requests



cookie = AMAZON_COOKIE = os.getenv("AMAZON_COOKIE", "")

#https://read.amazon.com/notebook

res = requests.get('https://read.amazon.com/notebook',
                       headers={
                           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                           'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                           'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
                           'Cookie': cookie
                       }
                       )

pprint(res.text)


def login():
    signin_page_res = requests.get('https://read.amazon.com/notebook',
                                   headers={
                                       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                                       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                       'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
                                   }
                                   )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(signin_page_res.text, 'html.parser')

    login_inputs = {}
    for input_tag in soup.find_all('input'):
        name = input_tag.get('name')
        value = input_tag.get('value')

        if not value and name not in ('email', 'password'):
            continue

        login_inputs[name] = value

    login_inputs['email'] = os.getenv("AMAZON_USERNAME", "email")
    login_inputs['password'] = os.getenv("AMAZON_PASSWORD", "pass")

    pprint(login_inputs)


    login_res = requests.post('https://read.amazon.com/notebook',
                              headers={
                                  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                                  'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0",
                              },
                              data=login_inputs
                              )
    print(login_res.text)
    with open('index.html','w',encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(login_res.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login()
```

Recently I found that there is one project called audible where they used the api to connect to the account of amazon, and fix the problem of the encryption of password. [here](https://github.com/mkb79/Audible)